# TYPO3 10.x - when using itemArrayProcFunc I can't get the id of the TextMenuContentObject

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

for many years I've been able to get the id of the TextMenuContentObject using the following code:

```
public function level2MenuAction($menuArr, $conf)
    {
        $pObj = $conf['parentObj'];
        $parentPageId = $pObj->id;
```

now I get the following Error, when I try:

> Cannot access protected property TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\Menu\TextMenuContentObject::$id

which makes sense since the id is protected.

[image]

I am not sure how I can now go about getting said id, since there is no getId() or other method that I have been able to find... Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Trying to access id of the TextMenuContentObject, but getting an error

Answer (score 0):

ahh, it seems I have just found the Answer myself:

```
public function level2MenuAction($menuArr, $conf)
    {
        $pObj = $conf['parentObj'];
        $parentPageUid = $conf['parentObj']->getParentMenuItem()['uid'];
        ...
```